# C++ Get ctrl-c and special keys to work to work when getting characters from users input on windows

Tags: c++, windows, exit, windows-console, ctrl

I'm trying to make a program where users enter in information and the program reads it character by character. I'm trying to use SetConsoleMode to change the console. I understand that I need ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT to be set, but when it is set arrow keys don't work. Additionally, it takes a entering another key for the enter key to be recognized. How do I fix this on windows?

```
  HANDLE hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  DWORD mode = 0;
  GetConsoleMode(hStdin, &mode);
  SetConsoleMode(hStdin, mode & ~(ENABLE_LINE_INPUT | ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT) | ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT);
  int c = getchar();
  SetConsoleMode(hStdin, mode);
  return c;
```

For clarification, I'm trapping the SIGINT from ctrl-c somewhere else, so I need the console to send the signal.

Comment: Your bit operations are wrong `mode &= ~(ENABLE_LINE_INPUT | ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT) // disable these
mode |= ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT;                  // enable this`

Comment: You're disabling the cooked read (i.e. `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT`) that actually implements line editing (i.e. cursor navigation via arrow keys, home, etc; history; and aliases), and it's probably not tested well to combine this with processed input. PowerShell does this at a lower level by calling `ReadConsoleInputW` and implements all of its own line editing, such as via its [PSReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/?view=powershell-7) module.

Comment: Reading low-level console input records can be tricky since pasted keyboard input can appear as a sequence of records per character. So I would first look for a C/C++ library that implements something like GNU Readline for the Windows console. That also has the potential benefit of making your program easily portable to other platforms.